# In Visual Studio, how do I call my Web API?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

In Visual Studio, I have one project that is an Angular application and a second project that is ASP.NET Web API. I am just starting work and don't want to post anything to production. Is there a way within Visual Studio to setup the Web API project so I can call it? I tried this:

```
        $http.get('http://localhost:45620/Sample.WebAPI/api/unitSizes')
        .then(onSizeRetrieveComplete, onError);
```

And several other variations of this, but I keep getting a 404 (not found).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "In visual studio"? Do you want *Visual Studio* to talk to your web service? Or some program you're making *with* Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured this out.

Several things have to happen to make this work:

1. Set the Solution Set Startup Projects to start up both projects.
2. Set the Web API project properties Web | Start Action to "Don't
   open a page."
3. Remove the name of the project from the url in the
   sample code. So it then looks like this:

   ```
       $http.get('http://localhost:45620/api/unitSizes')
       .then(onSizeRetrieveComplete, onError);
   ```
4. Ensure that, if using a plural name, you use the plural for the
   controller name as well (UnitSizesController).

That did it for me. Hope this helps someone else ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't code your javascript directly to your localhost, you will have a hard time publishing to production. Use a relative Url instead,

```
    $http.get('/api/unitSizes')
    .then(onSizeRetrieveComplete, onError);
```